# Программа зависает

Tags: c++builder, c++

Программа не выдает ошибок, а только виснет нажав на кнопку, вот листинг кнопки.

```
void __fastcall TForm2::Button3Click(TObject * Sender)
{

    float **m = new float *[N];

    float *s;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        m[i] = new float[N + 1];
    }
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    try {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
                m[i][j] = StrToFloat(Form2->StringGrid1->Cells[j + 1][i + 1]);
            }
        }
        k = 1;
        //Прямой проход (сверху вниз)
        for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
            //Поиск строки с ненулевым первым элементом
            for (j = i; j < N; j++) {
                if (m[j][i] != 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == N) {
                throw Exception("Вырожденная система с рангом " + IntToStr(i));
            }
            if (j != i) {
                //Меняем строки
                s = m[i];
                m[i] = m[j];
                m[j] = s;
            }
            //Вычитание строк
            for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
                if (m[j][i] == 0) {
                    //Уже нулевой элемент
                    continue;
                }
                float r = -m[j][i] / m[i][i];
                //Обнуляем начало строки
                for (int k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) {
                    m[j][k] = 0;
                }
                //вычитаем окончание строки
                for (int k = i + 1; k < N + 1; k++) {
                    m[j][k] += m[i][k] * r;
                }
            }
        }
        //Обратный проход(снизу вверх)
        for (i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            //Диагональный элемент делаем 1.
            m[i][N] = m[i][N] / m[i][i];
            m[i][i] = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                float r = -m[j][i] / 1;
                //Вычитание строк
                m[j][i] = 0;
                m[j][N] += m[i][N] * r;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                Form2->StringGrid1->Cells[i + 1][N + 1] = FloatToStrF(m[i][N], ffGeneral, 7, 4);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception & e) {
        if (k == 0) {
            ShowMessage("Ошибка при вводе элемента [" + IntToStr(i + 1) + "][" + IntToStr(j + 1) + "]." + (e.Message).c_str());
            //"Гаусс",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            Form2->StringGrid1->Col = j + 1;
            Form2->StringGrid1->Row = i + 1;
        } else {
            ShowMessage("Ошибка при решении системы.");        // (e.Message).c_str());
            //"Гаусс",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            delete[]m[i];
        }
        delete[]m;

}}
```

Comment: Тебе сказать что этот участок кода делает? Или в нем ошибка и ее надо найти? Тогда надо предоставить сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Ну сообщения-то он предоставить не сможет, судя по вопросу. А вот то, что исходной информации явно недостаточно, видно сразу.

Comment: не, а как вас это нравится??  
"Где-то на этом участке оно зависает..."  
вы когда-нибудь слышали про K&R стиль???

Comment: @Илья Михневич, а вы когда-нибудь слышали про обфускаторы? Да стиль-то -- ерунда, отформатировать недолго, а вот недостаток информации -- дело другое. При каких условиях оно зависает? Была ли реально "Ошибка при вводе элимента"? И т.д.

Comment: Что-то неладно у Вас с единственным делением по Гауссу, если это оно, конечно. 

float r = -m[j][i] / 1; - что это? Почему "единственное" деление у Вас производится и на обратном ходу тоже? Зачем приравнивать нижние элементы нулю, а диагональные единице - они и так 0 и 1 по определению, а на обратном ходу к ним не обращаются? Во время прямого хода искать надо не диагональный элемент неравный нулю, а наибольший по абсолютной величине. Пожалуйста, посмотрите как эту операцию рекомендуют в литературе и  не изобретайте велик по-новой :). Если хотите, поделюсь кодом, с которым работаю годами.

Comment: На бесконечный цикл в этом фрагменте не похоже. Границы и индексы внутри циклов IMHO не меняются. 

Могу посоветовать автору "кинуть несколько выводов на печать" (реально в файл) между внешними циклами и убедиться в этом.

Comment: @alexlz, просто я попытался прочитать, чтоб понять проблему и не смог. про остальное я просто промолчал

Answer (score 2):

Заметил только благодаря комментариям уважаемого [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp). Индексы **меняются** на обратном ходу (ходе), когда ведется запись в Грид. А все из-за того, что переменные циклов не локальны в цикле. Вообще, код надо менять - плохо написан.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. 

Везде в **for** ... Form2->StringGrid1->... автору надо все **i** поменять например на **j**.